# Poisson equation solution - regularity of the solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

The theorem states that if $f \in C^{2}_{0}(\mathbb R^{n})$, then function
$u(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^{n}} \phi(x-y)f(y)dy$ is the solution of
$-\Delta u(x)=f(x)$ and $u \in C^{2}(\mathbb R^{n})$. ($\phi$ is the fundamental Laplace equation solution)

I have a problem with the latter statement, I don't quite understand the proof. I know I can differentiate twice under the integral sign, but don't understand the proof of continuity of the second derivative.

We have $u_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^{n}} \phi(y)f_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x-y)dy$ for $i,j=1,2,...,n$. Now I want to prove the continuity of this partial derivative. It is done through Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. I would do something like this:

Let $x_{0} \in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be any sequence convergent to $x_{0}$. Now we have:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} u_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_{n}) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \phi(y)f_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_n -y)dy$

Now how to explain the interchange of integral sign and the limit using dominated convergence theorem? How to define a proper sequence of functions? I know that after this step it will be pretty easy to finish the proof because the support of $f$ is a compact set and $\phi$ is locally integrable, so the integral is bounded. Some definitons come to my mind as $g_n(x) := \phi(y)f(x_n -y)$ but it doesn't make sense to me as $g_n$ doesn't depend on $x$ and now I have a problem with $\phi$ as it is unbounded on any set containing $0$.

EDIT: I wonder if it could be done another way. I know that $f$ is bounded for any $y\in supp f$. Thus:

$|u_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_n) - u_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_0)| \le \sup_{y\in suppf}|f_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_n -y) - f_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_0 -y)|\int_{V} \phi(y)dy$,
where $V$ is some compact set.

Now taking the limit $n\to \infty$ we get the continuity of $u_{x_{i}x_{j}}$ as the supremum converges to $0$ and $\phi$ is locally integrable. Is it OK?

Comment: The notion of sifting is from the dirac delta function, that equals $ 1 $ if the difference of it's arugment, usually between the dependent and independent variable is $ 0 $. This was it is some-what a Darboux remedy, making the interval of integration continuous between two functions. The $ \phi $ function is likely to be some polynomial with a trivial kernel w.r.t the function $ f $. I would try to find $ \phi $ by expanding $ f $ as a power series and finding its convergence to some limit $ a $, of which is shared by $ \phi $.

Comment: @Cppg Will it be so complicated? It was stated in a lecture as if it was quite obvious and trivial. Would you mind have a look at my edit?

Comment: If the continuities of the ranges of both functions have some set relationship and one is a weak derivative, then the former statement holds to the mean value thereom and should by extension to Rolle's thereom.

Comment: But it was mentioned to be correct as a result of dominated convergence theorem. How is that done?  We should find some integrable function dominating  functions from a proper sequence. And how is the sequence defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem because $f$ has compact support: when $x\in K$, a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, the function $y \mapsto f_{x_i x_j}(x-y)$ vanishes outside the compact set $K - \text{supp}(f)$. It means that
$$|\phi(y)f_{x_i x_j}(x-y)| \le |\phi(y)|\mathbb{1}_{K - \text{supp}(f)}(y) \|f_{x_i x_j}\|_\infty  \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$$
Thus, the integrated function is dominated by an integrable function uniformly when $x\in K$. The continuity follows by dominated convergence because $f\in\cal{C}^2$.

Of course, it depends on what you know about the fundamental solution, but you told us you know it is locally integrable and this is sufficient.

Remark: one often uses $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in PDEs because it makes $n$ available for sequences, as you do with $x_n$.

Comment: What does it mean to be dominated uniformly? For any $y$? Isn't your answer the same as my edit? I have some doubts now regarding dominating convergence because I always used it in regard to sequences.

Comment: By uniformly, I mean that you are integrating a function $H(x, y)$ with respect to $y$, and this function is dominated by a function $J(y)\in L^1$ that *does not depend on* $x$. If you are using a sequence $x_n$, it means that $|H(x_n, y)| \le J(y)$, a bound independent of $n$ (or uniform with respect to $n$, which means the same thing). Of course, here, you get a uniform bound only if $x$ stays in a compact region of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Do I think correct that we can always make $x_n$ stay in a compact region of $\mathbb R^d$? Because the sequence converges to some point $x_0$ we can think of a closed ball with a center at $x_0$ and radius $\epsilon$. And there is only a countable set of points outside the ball which has Lebesgue measure $0$. Is that right? And what about the inequality in my edit of the question? Can we dominate it with a bound dependent of $n$ and then take $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Exactly, a converging sequence in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is bounded, hence it stays in a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (such as a convenient closed ball). You can dominate the function by a $L^1$ bound that does not depend on $n$, and that's precisely the hypothesis needed by the dominated convergence theorem. Also have a look at [this](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Parameter-dependent_integral).

Comment: Now I get it, thank you. But what about the approach where the dominating function is dependent on $n$ and then take the limit $n\to \infty$? There is no need of dominated convergence theorem and the statement is proved directly. We have $|u_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_n) - u_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_0)| \le \sup_{y\in supp f} |f_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_n - y) - f_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x_0 - y)| \int_{K} \phi(y)dy$, where $K$ is some compact set in $\mathbb R^n$. Now when we take $n\to \infty$ we get that $u_{x_{i}x_{j}}$ is continuous. Is this approach wrong?

Comment: And if you could clear out one thing, you defined a function $ y \rightarrow f_{x_{i}x_{j}}(x-y)$ which is in fact $ g_n(y) = f_{x_{i}x_{j}(x_n - y)$? And then by the dominated convergence theorem we get that $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{supp f} \phi(y)f_{x_{i}x_{j}(x_n - y)dy$ equals $ u_x_{i}x_{j}(x_0)$?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about the details, but it is true that $f_{x_i x_j}$ being continuous with compact support, it is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^d$. This means that $|f_{x_i x_j}(x_n-y) - f_{x_i x_j}(x_0-y)|\le \epsilon(x_n - x_0)$ independently of $y$, where $\epsilon$ is some real function tending to $0$ at $0$. You only need to be more specific on the assertion that $K$ *is some compact set*. The compact set must not depend on $n$. You can use a compact set similar to the one I used above for example.